# Original function is called instead of stub

Tags: javascript, express, mocha.js, stub, sinon

I'm having an issue getting Sinon's stub to work correctly for me. When I stub `list` on `retro` and the test runs, `app.get('/retro', retro.list)` is executing the original function `retro.list` instead of the stub.  Since this happens, the test fails because the stub's `callCount` is 0.

I'm more familiar with coffeescript and I have stubbed things in the same way.  Is there something I'm not understanding about Javascript's scoping, or how the `require('../routes/retro')` works, or is `retro` is not the same in `app.js` and `test.js`.

Much thanks for the help and code below.

test.js:

```
var request = require('supertest')
  , retro = require('../routes/retro')
  , app = require('../app')
  , sinon = require('sinon');
require('should'); 

describe('GET /retro', function() {
  // less involved, but maybe stupid to test
  it('should call retro.list', function(done) {
    var stub = sinon.stub(retro, 'list');

    request(app)
      .get('/retro')
      .end(function(err, res){
        stub.callCount.should.equal(1);

        if (err) return done(err);
        done();
      })
  })
})
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , config = require('./config')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , retro = require('./routes/retro');

var app = express();
config(app);

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/retro', retro.list);

module.exports = app;
```

retro.js:

```
var retro = {
  list: function(req, res){
    console.log('actual called');
    res.send("respond with a resource");
  }
}

module.exports = retro;
```

Comment: What does `retro` return? Is it a plain object or a newly created instance?

Comment: Try this `retro.list.callCount.should.equal(1);`

Comment: @mor I included `retro.js` so you can see the object it returns. It is not an instance. I was thinking of exporting an instance and trying to stub the protoype, but that wasn't working very well either.

Comment: @Sushanth-- I tried out your advice, but `sinon.stub(retro, 'list')` returns the stub on `retro.list` so they are the same object and running that code yielded the same problem.  Thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll likely need to create your stubs before requiring/creating the `app`.

```
var request = require('supertest')
  , sinon = require('sinon')
  , retro = require('../routes/retro');

var stubRetroList = sinon.stub(retro, 'list');

var app = require('../app');

// ...

    stubRetroList.callCount.should.equal(1);
```

This allows `retro.list` to be updated before it's passed to the route:

```
app.get('/retro', retro.list);
```

The issue is probably because `retro.list` isn't being passed-by-reference (pointer), but is rather a reference that's passed-by-value (copied). So, though `sinon.stub()` is altering `retro.list`, it wouldn't affect the copy that the `'/retro'` route already had.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! This worked perfectly. Not sure I like stubbing something up there, but I'm so glad I understand that it was stubbing a reference/copy as opposed to the same object.

Comment: [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) is a better solution for this

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and the accepted answer (while true) was of no help. Turns out in order for `sinon` stubbing to work the stubbed method cannot be used in the same module. In other words stubbing a module endpoint will only stub the module endpoint and not the internal usage of the function referenced by `module.exports`.

Explained via an example:

module.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).json(list())
})

function list() {
    return ['something']
}

module.exports = {
    router: router,
    list: list
}
```

module.spec.js

```
// This stub will not work
sinon.stub(module, 'list').callsFake(() => ['something else'])
```

To make it work you have separate what you want to stub into its own module and use it that way:

sub_module.js

```
function list() {
    return ['something']
}

module.exports = {
    list: list
}
```

Now `sub_module.list()` can be stubbed.

(OP defines a method in place so this is not an issue for him)